# Comparing h5 files

Tags: hdf5, hdf

I often have to compare `hdf` files. How I do it is either with a binary `diff` (which tells me files are different even though the actual numbers inside are the same) or by dumping the content into a txt file with `h5dump` and the comparing the content of the two files (which is also quite annoying).

I was wondering if there is a more clever way to do this, perhaps a feature of `h5` or of softwares like `HDFView` or `Panoply`.

Comment: usually comparing binary formats is a dead end; you definitely need specialized software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [hdiff](https://support.hdfgroup.org/doc_resource/h4_doc/util/hdiff/hdiff_index.html) is what you require ? Some examples [here](https://support.hdfgroup.org/doc_resource/h4_doc/util/hdiff/hdiff_examples.html)

Comment: That looks very much like what I was looking for.

Comment: The only thing is that at least for my version of `hdf5` (1.8.18) the command is `h5diff` instead of `hdiff` as mentioned in the example page.

Comment: hddif is for HDF4 files, h5diff is for HDF5.

Comment: links are broken now

Answer (score 0):

[h5diff](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html#Tools-Diff) can be used to compare HDF5 files, and on Ubuntu it can be installed with

```
apt-get install hdf5-tools
```

then it's simply

```
h5diff file1.hdf5 file2.hdf5
```

Comment: why isnt this question in `Cross Validated` section? i thought HDF5 is a specific format used in big data and alikes